# Problema al cargar un archivo desde el storage de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo lo siguiente, necesito enviar un archivo XML a un servicio soap, puedo consumir el servicio, pero tengo problemas al obtener el fichero que quiero mandar a dicho servicio, como estoy probando? tengo una variable data que me almacena la informacion necesaria:

```
$data=
            array (
                'SolicitudServicioRecepcionFactura' => 
              array (
                'codigoAmbiente' => config('configsoap.codigoAmbiente'),
                'codigoDocumentoSector' => $codDocSec, //de factura de compraventa
                'codigoEmision' => $codEmit, //1 para modaldiad online
                'codigoModalidad' => config('configsoap.codigoModalidad'), //1 electronica en linea 
                'codigoPuntoVenta' => config('configsoap.codigoPuntoVenta'),
                'codigoSistema' => config('configsoap.codigoSistema'),
                'codigoSucursal' =>config('configsoap.codigoSucursal'),
                'cufd' => $auxCodes->getCufd()['codigo_r'],
                'cuis'=>$auxCodes->getCuis()['codigo_r'],
                'nit' => config('configsoap.nit'),
                'tipoFacturaDocumento' => $typeInnvoice,
                 
                //Este es el fichero que quiero mandar, esta en mi storage, dentro de una carpeta llamada xmlInvoices, probe tambien quitando por delante lo de storage y nada
                'archivo' => Storage::get('storage/xmlInvoices/facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.xml'),
                'fechaEnvio' => '2022-01-01T19:23:23.23',
                'hashArchivo' => '1111111111111111',
              ),
        );
```

Cabe recalcar que hice un `php artisan storage:link` para que se enlace las carpetas respectivas.

Si por separado realizo un dump o un dd de la instrucción que obtiene el fichero xml, me retorna null:

```
dump(Storage::get('storage/xmlInvoices/facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.xml'));
dump(Storage::disk('local')->get('xmlInvoices/facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.xml'));
```

Soy nuevo incursionando en Laravel :s

Comment: Algunas aclaraciones: "The `get` method may be used to retrieve the contents of a file, entonces ¿quieres enviar el contenido del archivo, o el archivo en sí como adjunto?. "When using the `local` driver, all file operations are relative to the `root` directory defined in your `filesystems` configuration file. By default, this value is set to the `storage/app` directory.", entonces, ¿dónde está el archivo relativo al directorio `storage` de tu aplicación?

Comment: Disculpame, ya lo solucione, no entendía bien la parte del controlador y los directorios que mapeaba:

Storage::disk('public')->exist("xmlInvoices/$myFileName");

Comment: Ok, no hay necesidad de disculparse. Sólo estaba pidiendo esas aclaraciones para que tengas más posibilidades de obtener una respuesta. Lo que mencionas `Storage::disk('public')->exist('xmlInvoices/$myFileName')` te va devolver un booleano, o sea, `true` o `false`. ¿Cómo soluciona eso lo que estabas preguntando? Sería bueno cerrar la pregunta con una respuesta... Así le puede servir a otros usuarios que se encuentren con el mismo problema

Comment: disculpame la demora, recuperaba el fichero utilizando el metodo get de storage:    Storage::disk('public')->get('xmlInvoices/$myFileName')
Tambien existe la funcion url para que me retorne el path del fichero, pero en mi caso es raro si deseo invocar a esa funcion url() de la siguiente forma:
Storage::disk('public')->url('xmlInvoices/$myFileName')

No me reconoce la funcion url, pero si lo trabajo sin definir "disk" entonces la funcion es llamada de forma normal, raro raro

Laravel 9.x